# Primefaces weird behaviour with datatable, overlayPanel and filter/sort

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I'm having some trouble with primefaces datatables and dynamic overlay for each row.

Basically I have a main datatable containing a certain number of rows. For each row, I have a button and a linked overlay that, when clicked, shows a small datatable in the overlay (it lists the lasts changes concerning the row).

Here is the simplified code:

```
//the main datatable
<p:dataTable id="terminauxDataTable" var="terminalBean" widgetVar="dataTableWidgetVar" value="#{cc.attrs.listAllTerminals}" 
filteredValue="#{cc.attrs.listFilteredTerminals}">
...
<p:columnGroup>
  <p:row>
    <p:commandButton id="changelogButton"
               type="button"/>
    <p:overlayPanel id="changelogPanel" for="changelogButton"
       dynamic="true">
       //the small datatable for each row
       <p:dataTable var="changelog" value="#{terminalBean.lastChangelogs}">
          <p:column headerText="#{msg['commun.changelog.table.label.date']}">
              <h:outputText value="#{changelog.dateHr}">
                  <f:converter converterId="dateTimeConverter" />
              </h:outputText>
          </p:column>
          ... some other colums
       </p:dataTable>
    </p:overlayPanel>
</p:row></p:column></p:datatable>
```

everything works fine at first sight. When I click on any button i do get the content that I want to load. it's supposed to look like this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9GrW.png
(sorry, cannot post image directly)

Problems start to arise as soon as I make any filtering od sorting on the main datatable.
If a specific button was never clicked since page load, the overlay and the contained datatable are load successfuly. It dosen't matter if I applied a filter or a sort.
If I already clicked a button at least once and then I apply a sort/filter, if I try to click again on the button the overlay is shown but is empty, there is no datatable inside.

here is an exemple of a click after a filter on a button that was clicked before :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLGLo.png

Do you have any lead on how to address this problem ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the overlay opitimally with a datatable, requires a little different approach as can be seen in the [PrimeFaces showcase of the overlayPanel](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/overlayPanel.xhtml)

You need to put the overlayPanel **outside** the datatable, put a updatable container in there, e.g. an outputPanel and on the button in your column, update the panel and call the show function of the overlay panel with a specific parameter. Something like this:

```
<p:dataTable>
    ....
    <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
         <p:commandButton update=":form:terminalDetail" oncomplete="PF('myTerminalOP').show('#{component.clientId}')" icon="ui-icon-search" title="Details">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{selectedTerminal}" target="#{mySelectionView.selectedTerminal}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<p:overlayPanel widgetVar="myOP" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" dismissable="false" showCloseIcon="true">
    <p:outputPanel id="terminalDetail" style="text-align:center;">
    ...
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:overlayPanel>
```

(Disclaimer: done on my phone, so typos may be there)

Comment: I tried to use this without much success. The page simply don't render if I don't put "for" in the overlay panel with a stacktrace like :
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.primefaces.component.overlaypanel.OverlayPanelRenderer.encodeScript(OverlayPanelRenderer.java:70)
...

If I do put some value in it, obviously the overlay is not linked to the button but otherwise works. The code in primefaces showcase is incomplete and I don't understand where the component.clientId comes from.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What PF version are you using? and 'component' is a JSF built in variable that refers to the component that is in the current context.  And not complete? Just the imports, className and annotations are missing. For the realy full code, see the sourcecode in subversion?

Comment: By not complete, I meant that dtSelectionView is not on the showcase page, contrary to MovieView and ImageSwitchView. I Though that it may have had something necessary but now I see that i'm probably wrong. I'm using PF v4 right now and won't have the option to upgrade. At the very least I managed to make it work almost as intented with a dialog, but I would prefer the overlay if I can because it would be placed at the correct location and would be hidden with a click outside. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Ah yep I see. It is indeed a small glitch but I think you did get the point ;-) And now you also see why it is soooo important to post version info

Answer (score -4):

On latest version of primeng we can do this.
Triggering the event based on element #id. By doing the toggle from typescript, I was able to pin point the element I need to attach the overlay panel to.

HTML:

```
<div>
     <p-table>
          <--loop the data-->
          <button pButton (click)="showOP($event, rowwiseData, 'button'+rowIndex)" [id]="'button'+rowIndex"></button>
      </p-table>
</div>
<--outside of the table add the overlay menu-->
<p-menu #menu [popup]="true" [model]="panelData"></p-menu>
```

TS File:

```
panelData: any;
@ViewChild('menu', {static: false}) op: OverlayPanel;
<!--Call and point the event to the correct element using unique #id-->
showOverlayPanel($event: MouseEvent, rowwiseData: any, id:string) {
    this.panelData = rowwiseData;
    this.op.toggle($event,document.getElementById(id));
}
```

Comment: The question is about PrimeFaces (JSF, Java Server Faces, Jakarta Faces), not about PrimeNG.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).